# How to use this json struct for decoding in swift using JsonDecoder and print the coordinates

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

Ian building an app which uses son data for web service I used QuickType website to convert the son data to struct but now I don't know how to access the members of that structure after decoding the son data
This is my entire view controller file I need to decode and print the coordinate values so that I can access it in a map kit

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Foundation
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let locations: [Location]
}

// MARK: - Location
struct Location: Codable {
    let coordinates: Coordinates
    let country, countryCode: String
    let id: Int
    let latest: Latest
    let province: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coordinates, country
        case countryCode = "country_code"
        case id, latest, province
    }
}

// MARK: - Coordinates
struct Coordinates: Codable {
    let latitude, longitude: String
}

// MARK: - Latest
struct Latest: Codable {
    let confirmed, deaths, recovered: Int
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func btn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        loaddata()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




    }

    func loaddata()
    {

         let url = URL(string: "https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations")

        var session = URLSession.shared

        var data = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do
            {
                  var info =  try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data!)

                print(info.locations[0].coordinates.latitude)            }

            catch
            {
                print("\(error)")
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to convert a json object to a codable struct. Hope this helps!

```
do {
            let data = "\(yourJson)".data(
                using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false
            )

            let dataCodable = try JSONDecoder().decode(Coordinates.self, from: data!)
           print(dataCodable)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
```

Comment: What is should place in “\(your Json)”

Comment: Your json object. The one you are trying to convert

Comment: I tried JSONDecoder by passing  Welcome struct and accessing the array of location struct objects to print the coordinates the url returns an array of json objects

Comment: What was the output?

Comment: I didn’t get any output I tried print(info.location[0].coordinates.latitude)

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

Now I found out that I did not call resume() after shared data task so that it is not excecuting after adding it works flawlessly